# Windows Deployment Service tag synonymous to WDS tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Window Deployment Service is a technology include in Windows 2008 R2 for deployment microsoft operating systems using the LAN.

It's often shortened as WDS.

[windows-deployment-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-deployment-services) and [wds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wds) are tag and they both exists. Create a Synonymous please. 
Regards.

Comment: I don't see any [tag:windows-deployment-services] tag?

Comment: Yes you are right. Futher more i think ther is a typo with the tag. http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-deployment-servic

Comment: Ah, good catch :)

Comment: @mark see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now created. (note that we like questions to have answers, so please answer the question if they are completed..)